# How to get exact two columns of table(s) from a entair database in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

There are two tables - Entity table and Account table. Entity table having EntityID and Account table having AccountID. There is a 3rd table EntityAccountAssociation which contains both EntityID and AccountID. - This I know.

My scenario is; suppose in a product support, I do not know about this 3rd table (and no one is there to tell me) , then, is there any query to find out this 3rd table to get the relationship in a huge database with 100s of table?

```
For Example: In that query, I will pass these two column name as parameter   and it will show me on which particular table these two columns exists.
```

Please help and let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a query that returns table(s) with both columns, this would do:

```
-- DECLARE @col1 NVARCHAR(255) = 'X', @col2 NVARCHAR(255) = 'Y'
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME TablesContainingBoth
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (@col1, @col2)
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If only one table had both columns, it would return one result.